# JQuery UI Autocomplete refreshing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-autocomplete

[image]

**JQuery UI Autocomplete refreshing**
when i remove item from autocomplete text control its item is appearing until refresh the page so we want to rebind and refresh the autocomplete control

Comment: Could you please post some code on how you remove the item from list? Or a Demo Fiddle would be great.. :)

Comment: Solve this issue with bind custom label with remove per item click for each item wise. Thanks for your comments.